# How can get EditText from a class?

Tags: android, class, android-edittext, layout-inflater

How can get `EditText` from a class? I cannot get string from `EditText.getText().toString()`. It is null.

```
public class SignUpModel  {
    String email;
    Context context;

    public SignUpModel(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sign_up, null);
        EditText signup_email =(EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        email = signup_email.getText().toString();
        Log.v("email",signup_email.getText().toString());
        return email;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you added `layout ` View in current screen?

Answer (score 0):

Just create your global `EditText` variable, then get it. But, check null before using it.

```
public class SignUpModel  {
    String email;
    Context context;
    private EditText signup_email;

    public SignUpModel(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sign_up, null);
        signup_email =(EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        email = signup_email.getText().toString();
        Log.v("email",signup_email.getText().toString());
        return email;
    }
    public EditText getEmailEditText() {
       return signup_email;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is public void getEmailEditText() {return signup_email;} return void?

Comment: sorry, see my changed

Answer (score 0):

Just make string public static and access it in your class .Put on editText change listener and reinitialize your string .Hope it will help you .